# Android in Xamarin Studio - error: package com.google.android.gms.tagmanager does not exist

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin-studio, android-sdk-2.3

I am getting following errors when trying to build a project in Xamarin Studio. I am suspecting that I am missing some Android SDK package but I am not sure which one.

> obj\Debug\android\src\mono\com\google\android\gms\tagmanager\ContainerHolder_ContainerAvailableListenerImplementor.java(8,52):
>   javac error :  error: package
>   com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.ContainerHolder does not exist
>   obj\Debug\android\src\mono\com\google\android\gms\tagmanager\ContainerHolder_ContainerAvailableListenerImplementor.java(8,52):
>   javac error :
>         com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.ContainerHolder.ContainerAvailableListener
>   obj\Debug\android\src\mono\com\google\android\gms\tagmanager\ContainerHolder_ContainerAvailableListenerImplementor.java(8,52):
>   javac error :
>
> obj\Debug\android\src\mono\com\google\android\gms\tagmanager\ContainerHolder_ContainerAvailableListenerImplementor.java(27,69):
>   javac error :  error: package com.google.android.gms.tagmanager does
>   not exist
>   obj\Debug\android\src\mono\com\google\android\gms\tagmanager\ContainerHolder_ContainerAvailableListenerImplementor.java(27,69):
>   javac error :     public void onContainerAvailable
>   (com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.ContainerHolder p0,
>   java.lang.String p1)
>   obj\Debug\android\src\mono\com\google\android\gms\tagmanager\ContainerHolder_ContainerAvailableListenerImplementor.java(27,69):
>   javac error :
>
> obj\Debug\android\src\mono\com\google\android\gms\tagmanager\ContainerHolder_ContainerAvailableListenerImplementor.java(32,79):
>   error :  error: package com.google.android.gms.tagmanager does not
>   exist
>   obj\Debug\android\src\mono\com\google\android\gms\tagmanager\ContainerHolder_ContainerAvailableListenerImplementor.java(32,79):
>   error :   private native void n_onContainerAvailable
>   (com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.ContainerHolder p0,
>   java.lang.String p1);
>   obj\Debug\android\src\mono\com\google\android\gms\tagmanager\ContainerHolder_ContainerAvailableListenerImplementor.java(32,79):
>   error :

The minimum API of the project is 10.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue. The problem was corrupted file that Xamarin has downloaded.

[image]

Following zip file was corrupted, after re-downloading it from https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r19.zip

replaced the file and re-build fixed the problem.